# Is there an easy way to deserialize a JSON string leaving all arrays as strings?

Tags: json, json.net, c#-7.0

Basically what I would like to do is deserialize just one level JSON (initially the top) into an ExpandoObject, but convert all properties at that level (found to be array), to JSON strings (instead of recursively deserializing them into Lists of their own).

So something like this:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "one",
   "contacts": [
     { "name": "john", "email":"john@somewhere.com" },
     { "name": "jane", "email":"jane@somewhere.com" }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "two",
   "contacts": [
     { "name": "jess", "email":"jess@somewhere.com" },
     { "name": "jenn", "email":"jenn@somewhere.com" }
   ]   
 }
]
```

would generate an ExpandoObject which is a List<Expando> with a Int32 Id, String name, and String contacts as properties, where there contacts are converted to be a JSON string as such:

```
"[{\"name\":\"john\","email\":\"john@somewhere.com\"},{\"name\":\"jane\",\"email\":\"jane@somewhere.com\"}]"
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the JSON, what you want to happen and what actually happens? It sounds unlikely that you'd be able to do this particularly easily, partly as it sounds like an unusual use case.

Comment: I added an example in the original post. I realize this is a highly specialized case, but I'm working with some pretty rough constraints within a reporting engine. Which I am writing a custom data provider for.

Comment: I would probably parse it as a `JObject`, and build your `ExpandoObject` from that. You may lose some details in terms of whitespace within the array representation, but that's probably okay. I'll write up an example...

Comment: I note that your JSON is actually for an array as the outer part, so I'm going to assume you want a `List<ExpandoObject>`...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a common use case, so there's no existing support for it that I'm aware of.

I'd use Json.NET's LINQ to JSON, then convert what you need to when populating the `ExpandoObject`. Here's an example that seems to work for your sample data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        JArray top = JArray.Parse(json);
        var expandos = top
            .Cast<JObject>()
            .Select(ConvertToExpando)
            .ToList<dynamic>();
        Console.WriteLine(expandos[0].id);       // 1 (as an Int64)
        Console.WriteLine(expandos[0].name);     // one
        Console.WriteLine(expandos[0].contacts); // JSON
    }

    static ExpandoObject ConvertToExpando(JObject jobject)
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = expando;
        foreach (var pair in jobject)
        {
            dictionary[pair.Key] = ConvertValue(pair.Value);
        }
        return expando;

        object ConvertValue(JToken token)
        {
            switch (token)
            {
                case JArray array:
                    return array.ToString();
                case JValue value:
                    return value.Value;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Can't handle {jobject.GetType()} yet");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Json.Linq option, if you don't mind a little overhead, you can just let the entire deserialization happen, then loop through each ExpandoObject as a Dictionary to replace the collection properties as such:

```
  List<ExpandoObject> expandoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jsonString, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

  foreach (ExpandoObject expando in expandoList) {
    IDictionary<string, object> expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (expandoDict != null) {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in expandoDict) {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable<Object>).IsAssignableFrom(kvp.Value.GetType())) {
          expandoDict[kvp.Key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp.Value);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```